# Grab FindUploader object from UI element

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I initialize a UI element with FineUploader, however I dont have a good way to keep a reference.  I want to update say something like the URL being used by it, but how can I do this from grabbing the element again like below?  It should just update the option and not the entire uploader again.

```
$(element).fineUploader({ url: 'oldUrl']);

$(element).fineUploader({ url: 'newurl']); // <--- Possible?
```

Comment: `url` is not a valid configuration option.  What are you trying to do exactly?  Also, the jQuery plug-in wrapper is more trouble than it's worth.  Why not just use the vanilla JavaScript API instead?

Comment: URL is just an example, can you answer the question to the overall arch of the problem.  I dont have to use JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change a parameter after initializing the plug-in, you must do so via one of [the API methods](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html).  For example, to change the endpoint url: `uploader.setEndpoint(newUrl);` or if you are using the jQuery plugin wrapper: `$(element).fineUploader('setEndpoint', newUrl);`.

Comment: Ok so I can grab the uploader reference from doing the `.findUploader` on the element again.  Ill try it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, the Fine Uploader jQuery plugin wrapper stores an instance of the uploader, when it is initially created, in jQuery's data cache.  This entry in the cache is connected to the element.